# How can I open my horse's inventory?

Tags: pc, the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

According to the player manual you can bring up the companion command menu by long-pressing E while aiming your reticule at a companion. I would assume the same philosophy holds for horses, but I am unable to make it work.

Is there any other way to bring up my horses inventory? Or am I simply misinformed?

Comment: bigger question: does the horse have an inventory?

Comment: I had read some articles hinting that they in fact do. Now I know it was just bad phrasing for "use your horse to fast travel even while encumbered".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only human companions have an inventory, your horse does not.  However, your horse will allow you to carry more than your normal load and travel at full speed.

Comment: And what i found important, it lets you quick travel even if you're carrying to much.